# How to get the info from all the child windows onto a another window

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2012

I have problem in Visual Basic.net. I am new to this, so i got stuck at this one prob. The problem is:
1) I have a main window which calls few sub windows("employees') into the form. the main window looks like this[image: Main Window]

2)Now i can add some child windows to the main window by the FIle--> Add --> employee method. Now if i call the summary window which should take the salary information from all the employee child windows (i was'nt able to do this). this is the problem i have. Basically i want to add the salary values of all the employees and display it in the summary window. The main window +2 employee child window+ summary window looks like this below:
[image]

I attached the code in the drive and the link is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3pYsPcEtJWM1VIWEpPWnVyaU0/view?usp=sharing

So please can anyone help with this? Thank you

Comment: your link ask for permissions

Comment: ok just a min i will give permissions. sorry i forgot that, i changed the permissions now

Comment: now can you access it @DiegoLópez, just let me know if you cannot

Comment: can anyone help me with this

Comment: You need to stop thinking of forms as being your primary objects of functionality.  Forms should be used to display information, not to manage, contain or manipulate data.  I would suggest creating an Employee class that includes name and salary information and then a separate class that maintains a collection of all active employees.  This second class can be used to pass information about the aggregate salaries to and from different forms.